# unable to detect data with angularjs from json file

Tags: angularjs, json

It might be an easy one for most of you, but i've just started with angularjs.

I'm following [this example](http://www.webdeveasy.com/angularjs-data-model/) to create a data model in angularjs.

Just like in the example below, i'm creating a class with all the data-related actions so that i will be able to call the same model and use it elsewhere.

```
.factory('DataTest', ['$http', function ($http) {
        function DataTest(Data) {
            if (Data) {
                this.setData(Data);
            }
        };
        DataTest.prototype = {
            setData: function (Data) {
                angular.extend(this, Data);
            },
            load: function (id){
                var scope = this;
                $http.get('json/data.json').success(function(Data){
                    scope.setData(Data);
                });
            },
            delete: function(){
                $http.delete();
            },
            update: function (){
                $http.put();
            }
        };
        return DataTest;
    }])
```

When I create the scope in my controller like this:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'DataTest', function ($scope, DataTest) {
    $scope.test = new DataTest();
    console.log($scope.test);
    $scope.test.load();
 }])
```

The result in my console looks like this:

```
DataTest{}
   data: Array [7]
      0: Object
      1: Object
      2: Object
      3: Object
      ...
```

Now, i need to get inside `data` and i tried in a couple of ways with no luck:

```
$scope.test = new DataTest();
$scope.test2 = $scope.test.data;
console.log($scope.test2); //Console says 'Undefined'
$scope.test.load();

-----------------------------

$scope.test = new DataTest();
$scope.test2 = $scope.test.data;
console.log($scope.test2); 
$scope.test.data.load(); //Console says 'Cannot read property load of undefined'

------------------------

Tried returning DataTest.data from my DataTest service, and console says:
//'Provider 'DataTest' must return a value from $get factory method.'
```

How can i properly access the 'data' array inside my test scope?
Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

The JSON file (example):

```
"tm": "2015-12-24T15:43:29+0100",
"data": [
    {
      "ID": 0,
      "Type": 1,
      "Name": "test 0"
    },
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Type": 3,
      "Name": "test 1"
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "Type": 4,
      "Name": "test 2"
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your json file.whether it is prepared well json format or nor.
try with this:

data[0].something

It may get the json data.

Comment: json is well formatted, as i'm being using another way to fetch data until today. Also, if i expand data->0->the object values are all there

Comment: Are you able to share your json?

Comment: json is done. Do you resolved service callback function.

Comment: $http.get('json/data.json').success(function(Data){
                    scope.setData(Data.data);
                });

Comment: I added "Data.data" just go through it.In Service.

Comment: Enjoy a day :),Its not luck its just awareness of how data comes. thanks bro.